# Por qué no es necesario añadir el tipo de dato < > en la instanciación de un HashSet?

Tags: java, poo, estructuras-de-datos, iteradores

Por qué no es necesario añadir el tipo de dato < String > en la instanciación de `HashSet`?

Al principio (al ver al codigo a simple vista) pense que iba haber un 'error' en la compilación del programa porque se supone que los elementos de un `HashSet` son objetos cualesquiera y por tanto lo que saldría de `System.out.println(i.next());` serían direcciones de memoria, porque no hubo castings ni tampoco este tipo de especificación `<String>` en la instanciación, sin embargo el output fue correcto: `a  e u i o`.

Por qué?

```
public class Ejercicio13sep {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Set list = new HashSet();
        list.add("a");
        list.add("e");
        list.add("i");
        list.add("a");
        list.add("e");
        list.add("o");
        list.add("i");
        list.add("u");
        list.add("u");

        Iterator i = list.iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(i.next());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Respuesta breve y código de prueba

1. No es obligatorio indicar el tipo de dato al crear una nueva instancia del `HashSet` porque en realidad lo que se crea es una nueva instancia de `HashMap` y éste admite crear instancias sin indicar el tipo de dato.
   La [documentación](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html) dice lo siguiente sobre el constructor de `HashSet`;

> Construye un nuevo conjunto vacío; la instancia `HashMap` de respaldo
>   tiene capacidad inicial predeterminada (16) y factor de carga (0,75).

2. En cuanto a la salida, se imprimen los datos tal cual se ingresaron mediante `put`. No hay necesidad de ningún casting, porque los datos siempre tuvieron su tipo.

La clave para entender lo que ocurre se encuentra en la [descripción del método `add()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#add-E-):

> Agrega el elemento especificado a este conjunto si aún no está
>   presente. De forma más formal, añade el elemento especificado `e` a
>   este conjunto si este conjunto no contiene ningún elemento `e2` tal
>   que (`e == null? e2 == null: e.equals(e2)`). Si este conjunto ya
>   contiene el elemento, la llamada deja el conjunto sin cambios y
>   devuelve false.

#### Prueba de lo afirmado en el punto 2.

Si modificas el código de esta manera, preguntando al iterator de qué clase es cada elemento dentro del `HashSet`:

```
    Set otroHash = new HashSet();
    otroHash.add("x");
    otroHash.add("y");
    otroHash.add("z");

    ArrayList arrTest = new ArrayList();

    Set list = new HashSet();
    list.add("a");
    list.add(true);
    list.add(1);
    list.add(1.90);
    list.add(otroHash);
    list.add(arrTest);

    System.out.println(list);

    Iterator i = list.iterator();
    while (i.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(i.next().getClass());
    }
```

Tendrás por consola esto:

```
[a, 1, [], 1.9, [x, y, z], true]    

class java.util.HashSet
class java.lang.String
class java.lang.Integer
class java.util.ArrayList
class java.lang.Double
class java.lang.Boolean
```

> **¿Dónde ocurrió la conversión de tipos?  En ninguna parte... lo elementos se agregaron tal cual mediante `put`.  Eso es lo que muestra
>   el [código fuente de la clase](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java).**

Quizá pueda haber confusión y creer que `HashSet` crea una instancia genérica de `Object` al ver la declaración de `PRESENT` en la clase. Pero `PRESENT` es usado sólo para comparar, es decir, `PRESENT` **nunca**  es agregado al Set final.

---

## Profundizando

Sugiero que leas el siguiente artículo al respecto: [How HashSet Works Internally In Java?](https://netjs.blogspot.com/2015/09/how-hashset-works-internally-in-java.html)

Se hace un análisis del funcionamiento interno de `HashSet`, basándose en el código fuente.

Lo más relevante es lo siguiente:

### Constructores

... el punto más importante es que `HashSet` internamente utiliza `HashMap` para almacenar sus objetos. Dentro del `HashSet` hay muchos constructores, uno sin ningún parámetro y varios más con capacidad inicial o factor de carga, pero cada uno de estos constructores crea un `HashMap`. Si sabes [cómo funciona `HashMap` internamente en Java](http://netjs.blogspot.in/2015/05/how-hashmap-internally-works-in-java.html), es fácil entender cómo funciona `HashSet` internamente.

En el [código fuente de la clase `HashSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java) puedes ver que los constructores de la clase crean un `HashMap` en cualquier caso.

Por ejemplo en tu caso ocurre esto:

```
 /**
     * Constructs a new, empty set; the backing <tt>HashMap</tt> instance has
     * default initial capacity (16) and load factor (0.75).
     */
    public HashSet() {
        map = new HashMap<>();
    }
```

### `add()`

Otra clave para entender lo que ocurre es el método `add()`, que en el código fuente aparece así:

```
   /**
     * Adds the specified element to this set if it is not already present.
     * More formally, adds the specified element <tt>e</tt> to this set if
     * this set contains no element <tt>e2</tt> such that
     * <tt>(e==null&nbsp;?&nbsp;e2==null&nbsp;:&nbsp;e.equals(e2))</tt>.
     * If this set already contains the element, the call leaves the set
     * unchanged and returns <tt>false</tt>.
     *
     * @param e element to be added to this set
     * @return <tt>true</tt> if this set did not already contain the specified
     * element
     */
    public boolean add(E e) {
        return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;
    }
```

Siempre que insertes un elemento en `HashSet` usando el método `add()`, en realidad creas una entrada en el objeto de `HashMap` de respaldo interno con el elemento que has especificado como clave y una constante llamada "`PRESENT`" como su valor. Este "`PRESENT`" se define en la clase `HashSet` como se muestra a continuación:

```
// Dummy value to associate with an Object in the backing Map
    private static final Object PRESENT = new Object();
```

**La clave es esta: `return map.put(e, PRESENT)==null;`**

Puedes notar que el método `add()` de la clase `HashSet` llama internamente al método `put()` para respaldar el objeto `HashMap` pasando el elemento que has especificado como clave y la constante "`PRESENT`" como su valor.

Eso significa que cuando agregas algo al `HashSet` con `add()` es lo mismo que si agregaras valores a un mapa. ¿Hay casting cuando usas `put` en un mapa, o los valores se insertan con sus tipos en el mapa? (ver pruebas de código)

### Leer los valores (`Iterator`)

En `HashSet` no hay método `get` como se proporciona en `Map` o `List`. Para leer los valores se usa `Iterator`, que itera a través de los valores del Set. Internamente llamará al conjunto de llaves del `HashMap`, ya que los valores se almacenan como claves en el `HashMap`, de modo que lo que obtendremos son los valores almacenados en el `HashSet`.

Así es como el iterador se implementa en el `HashSet` internamente:

```
/**
 * Returns an iterator over the elements in this set.  The elements
 * are returned in no particular order.
 *
 * @return an Iterator over the elements in this set
 * @see ConcurrentModificationException
 */
public Iterator<E> iterator() {
    return map.keySet().iterator();
}
```

En definitiva, leer un `HashSet` mediante `Iterator` es como si estuvieras iterando sobre las llaves de un `HashMap`, las cuales fueron agregadas mediante `put`.

Comment: en `HashSet` se usa `Iterator` para imprimir valores aunque también pudo haber sido directo, es decir, `System.out.println(list);` y es lo mismo

Comment: Correcto @Michelle, de hecho, en el código hay un `System.out.println(list);`que imprime todo lo que hay dentro del `HashSet`:  `[a, 1, [], 1.9, [x, y, z], true]`.

Answer (score 2):

Aunque no esta en la documentación de [HashSet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashSet.html#HashSet(java.util.Collection)), al llamar al constructor sin definirle el tipo de colección que se usara, usa la clase Object[] por defecto, y puedes añadirle tanto String, como Integers. Pero si defines tanto el Set o el HashSet como String, o Integer, o alguna otra clase solo se podrán añadir objetos de la misma clase.

Por ejemplo:

Sin errores:

```
Set lista = new HashSet();
lista.add(1); //Añadimes un integer
lista.add("String"); //Añadimos un String
lista.add(10L); // Añadimos un Long
```

Con error:

```
Set<String> lista = new HashSet<String>();
lista.add(1); //Añadimos un integer
lista.add("String"); //Añadimos un String
lista.add(10L); // Añadimos un Long
```

La segunda opción al definir el Set solo aceptara objetos de tipo String.

En el primer caso, al no especificar el tipo de dato, se usa por defecto Object. Entonces, al hacer un System.out.println(objeto), lo que hace es un [String.valueof(objeto)](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println(java.lang.Object)), y en este caso el objeto es un String, por lo que no tiene problemas al convertir el tipo de objeto.

Comment: Pero porque aquí no importa especificar el dato y sí importa en un `List lista=new ArrayList()` por ejemplo?. Si en un `List` se manda a imprimir y si no se especificó el tipo de dato o  no se hicieron castings, lo que imprimiría `System.out.println(i.next());` serían direcciones de memoria.

Comment: En este caso, al no especificar el tipo de dato, se usa por defecto Object. Entonces, al hacer un System.out.println(objeto), lo que hace es un String.valueof(objeto), y en este caso el objeto es un String, por lo que no tiene problemas al convertir el tipo de objeto.

Comment: Esta respuesta no es correcta. Cuando se escribe `new HashSet();`  con o sin tipo de colección, **siempre se crea un `HashMap`** ([ver código fuente de la Clase `HashSet`](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java)) y sus diferentes constructores.

Comment: @A.Cedano pero al no escribir la colección, se crea un HashMap, no digo que no, pero que tipo de clase usa? No usa la clase Object? por eso se puede añadir todos los objetos que vienen de la clase object como Strings o Integers, Longs...

Comment: Tampoco. Revisa en el código fuente el método `add` y verás cómo funciona: `map.put(e, PRESENT)` agrega los elementos con `put`.

Comment: @JoseLuisMontañes Si no se especifica un tipo de boundary, se utiliza `java.lang.Object`, eso está garantizado por los [erasure](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/genTypes.html), en realidad las clases genéricas, no son genéricas, se impide el casting porque el compilador lo infiere.

Comment: Sea `A` una clase genérica (o parametrizada) en java , entonces existe una clase `A'` la cuál NO es una clase parametrizada.  De tal forma que todo nombramiento a `A`, el compilador inferira los castings necesarios para utilizar `A'`  como sinónimo de `A` sin pérdidas semánticas. Por tanto`A = A'`, es decir son iguales semánticamente.

Comment: @JoseLuisMontañes se crea concretamente un `HashMap` y cuando se itera sobre el `HashSet` no hay que hacer ningún casting, porque al iterar sobre él se itera sobre el `keySet()`.

Comment: @A.Cedano He revisado la documentacion de HashSet y HashMap, y en el put() que me comentas, el PRESENT, es de tipo Object, con lo cual si que hace uso de la clase `java.lang.Object` al no declarar el tipo de objetos, como comenta el compañero EduenSarceño

Comment: Pero el  `PRESENT` se agrega como `value` del Mapa, no como `key`, usando `map.put(e, PRESENT)`

Comment: @Jose Luis Montañes tu respuesta es elementalmente la mía pero sin tantos detalles técnicos que pueden confundir al OP, así que voto positivo.

Answer (score 2):

## Explicación corta

Es cierto, el valor devuelto por el iterador es un *String* pero casteado a *Object*, es decir, internamente sigue siendo un *String* pero no tenemos forma alguna de acceder a sus métodos de *String* (y en general,  no tenemos forma alguna de saber si efectivamente se trata de un *String*, a no ser que se pregunte directamente a través de introespección). Por el contrario si hubieses utilizado el operador diamante `<>` para indicar semánticamente que los objetos en cuestión son *Strings*, entonces el valor devuelto por el iterador sería un *String* como tal, con todos sus métodos.

En tu caso, tu recibes un *String* `x` identificado como *Object* por tanto el hacer `System.out.println(iterator.next())` no utiliza el método con el prototipo *System.out.println(String)*, si no el método con el prototipo *System.out.println(Object)*, puesto que `x` se identifica a sí mismo como *Object*

El método *System.out.println(Object)* imprime el valor de *Object.toString()*.

Todos tus objetos son *Strings*, y éstos sobre escriben el método *Object.toString*, tal como lo indica [*String.toString()*](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toString()).

> El valor devuelto por `String.toString()` ¡se trata de él mismo!

Entonces por polimorfismo, una instancia `a` de la clase `A` mantiene intacto sus métodos incluso en el caso en que `a` se identique como instancia de una clase `B`.

Por tanto si `x` es un *String* el hacer `x.toString()` devuelve `x`

Los pasos son

```
System.out.println((Object) x) 
= System.out.println(x.toString()) 
= System.out.println((String)x)
```

Si `x` desde un comienzo se identificara a sí mismo como *String* entonces los pasos se reducen a

```
System.out.println((String) x)
```

## Fondo

El ¿por qué? Se debe a la funcionalidad de la salida estándar del sistema, la cuál está garantizado por [`PrintStream.println`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/System.html),  el método `println` está sobrecargado para varios tipos, entre ellos el más genérico: `Object`

Al hacer `System.out.println(Object x)` el sistema ejecuta [`String.valueOf(Object x)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#valueOf(java.lang.Object)) para obtener una representación textual del objeto (éste último también ejecuta `Object.toString()`), finalmente imprime la representación textual del objeto (por lo general valores Hash)

> por tanto lo que saldría de System.out.println(i.next()); serían direcciones de memoria, porque no hubo castings

Lo anterior es falso, si una clase sobre escribe el método `Object.toString()`, lo que se visualizaría en consola sería el string resultante de llamar dicha función. En el caso concreto de la clase `String` el método `String.toString()` devuelve el mismo string, por obvias razones: la representación textual de un objeto string, es él mismo

Para verlo mejor, presta atención al siguiente código:

```
public class Pregunta101900 
{
        static class Digito
        {
                private int valor;

                public Digito(int digito)
                {
                        if (digito < 0 || digito > 9){
                                throw new RuntimeException("No es un dígito");
                        }
                        this.valor = digito;
                }

                @Override
                public String toString()
                {
                        return nombres[valor];
                }

                public String toString2()
                {
                        return super.toString();
                }

                private final static String nombres[] = new String[]{
                        "cero", "uno", "dos", "tres", "cuatro", "cinco", "seis",
                        "siete", "ocho", "nueve"        
                };

        }

        public static void main(String[] args)
        {
                Object d = new Digito(3);
                System.out.println(d);
                System.out.println(d.toString());
                System.out.println(((Digito)d).toString2());
        }
}
```

## Resumen

En el anterior código, se crea una clase llamada `Digito` que sobreescribe el método `Object.toString` de tal forma de devolver el nombre en castellano de un entero del 0-9. `Digito` además declara un nuevo método llamado `toString2` que permite acceder al método original `toString` declarado en `Object`. El cometido del programa es ver qué se imprimen en consola

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
            Object d = new Digito(3);
            System.out.println(d);
            System.out.println(d.toString());
            System.out.println(((Digito)d).toString2());
    }
```

Ejecutando el código:

```
[eduen@EDUENPC Escritorio]$ javac Pregunta101900.java; java Pregunta101900
tres
tres
Pregunta101900$Digito@15db9742
```

## Observaciones

EL anterior código castea `Digito` a su clase padre `Object` ésto con pérdidas semánticas (en el sentido de que no tenemos acceso a los métodos definidos en Digito que no estén en Object). La razón del casting en el tercer print, es simplemente para tener acceso a `toString2`.

## Conclusión

Como puedes ver, son un montón de detalles técnicos, y en general no es sencillo de explicar, tu pregunta utiliza varios conceptos, algunos relevantes y otros no tanto. En éste caso tu hablas de clases genéricas pero en ningún momento el compartamiento anormal se debe a ellos.

Comment: Muy bien todo eso, pero cuando creas un `HashSet` sin parámetros, lo que haces es crear un `HashMap`. Y cuando lo lees, lo que haces es iterar sobre un `HashMap`. [Revisa el código fuente de la Clase](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/HashSet.java)

Comment: @A.Cedano las clases genéricas son irrelevantes en éste caso, tanto como si utiliza  `<>` o sin él, el resultado es el mismo. Lo único que difiere es que el hacer `iterator.next()`, el valor defuelto será un `Object` en lugar de un  `String` contrario a si se hubiese utilizado el operador diamente <>. Sea cual sea el caso, se llamará al método `println(Object x)` o bien `println(String x)`. Puesto que `String.toString()`devuelve a él mismo, entonces `println(Object x) = println(String x)` si el objeto x es un String. **QED**

Comment: @A.Cedano la pregunta original es por el valor que se imprime en consola, jamás he tocado el tema de clases genéricas porque a) Es complicar el tema innecesariamente, b) No explica la pregunta del OP

Comment: No he mencionado en ningún momento las clases genéricas. Lo que se crea es un `HashMap`, no un objeto indefinido. Y cuando se itera tampoco devuelve un objeto indefinido, sino un `keySet`. Está muy claro en el código fuente, hay que revisarlo antes de _suponer_ que funciona de otra manera. Por ejemplo, el `toString()` no tiene nada que ver, el código fuente muestra que el iterator devuelve las claves y valores del `HashSet`

Comment: @A. Cedano El método `public Iterator <E> iterator()` es un acceso directo al iterador de las claves del miembro `map`, jamás devuelve un `keySet` es más `keySet` ni siquiera es un tipo, es un método de `Map` que devuelve un `Set` semánticamente hablando "Un conjunto de claves". No puedes afirmar que el valor devuelto es un `keySet` cuando el propio prototipo indica que es un `Iterator`. Dejando el debate a un lado, siento un poco ofensivo el "hay que revisarlo", asumo buena fé.

Answer (score 1):

Usar genéricos no es obligatorio en ningún caso. Java siempre ha sido un ejemplo de la retrocompatibiliddad (en mi opinión incluso demasiado) y, puesto que los genéricos fueron añadidos a la especificación del lenguaje en la versión 1.5, el código anterior debía seguir funcionando. Por tanto cualquier colección puede ser usada sin especificar el tipo de dato que contienen, y lo mismo pasa con cualquier clase o interfaz que use genéricos (List, Set, Map, Class, Comparable, Comparator, Future...)

Por otro lado, es **siempre** aconsejable usarlos, y el compilador te dará avisos (warnings) si no los usas.

Código válido:

```
List list= new ArrayList();
list.add("Hola");
Set conjunto=new HashSet(list);
String s= (String) list.get(0); //Casting porque get devuelve un Object
```

Código aconsejable, con la sintaxis más moderna:

```
List<String> list= new ArrayList<>();
list.add("Hola");
Set<String> conjunto=new HashSet<>(list);
String s=list.get(0); // No hace falta un casting
```