# Tengo una duda con la Serialización

Tags: java

Es necesario recoger en otro objeto el objeto serializado?? 
Aqui está el código...

```
package serializacion;
import java.io.*;
public class MainAlumnos {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception{

        Alumnos altas=new Alumnos("322","Felipe","Apellido","1718dm322","*****");


        ObjectOutputStream envio=new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream("C:\\Users\\adminportatil\\Desktop\\Alumnos.zip"));

        envio.writeObject(altas);
        envio.close();

        ObjectInputStream recibo=new ObjectInputStream (new FileInputStream("C:\\Users\\adminportatil\\Desktop\\Alumnos.zip"));

        Alumnos clase_recuperado=(Alumnos) recibo.readObject();//esto es necesario???? 

        recibo.close();

        System.out.println(clase_recuperado);//no se puede poner el objeto deObjectInpuctStream?????

    }

}
```

Comment: No tengo claro que quieres hacer... ¿Evitar tener que crear una variable? Puedes hacer `System.out.println(recibo.readObject())`, si simplemente quieres mostrarlo en pantalla

Comment: si hago eso me muestra en pantalla lo siguiente:
    java.io.ObjectInputStream@3d075dc0
Yo quiero saber  si es necesario recoger el recibo.readObject() en una variable (en mi caso a un objeto)del mismo tipo a lo que se a serializado

Comment: @HelloThere Si te pone java.io.ObjectInputStream@3d075dc0 lo que estás poniendo es System.out.println(recibo);`, y no lo que te he puesto. El método readObject no devuelve un Stream

Comment: Esta respuesta también lo explica bastante bien: https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/101907/14311

Comment: Serializar es convertir objeto a bytes, pero cuando son bytes no sabes qué es sólo son ceros y unos, por eso no podrías directamente usar el stream, un stream no son los bytes como tal, es un objeto que te ayuda a leerlos y escribirlos